# Error when calling querystring (qs) from browser

Tags: javascript, browser, require

I can't use requirejs on browser. So, I am using `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qs/6.5.1/qs.min.js`; however, it doesn't work when I call qs, I get this error:

```
VM79:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: qs is not defined
```

I am calling this way:

```
qs.stringify({'website_id' : website_id});
```

Answer (score 3):

I noticed in the source code that `qs` is not being defined, but `Qs`, the first character in uppercase.

[image]